# How to create specific number of columns dynamically based on a condition given a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create dynamic number of columns based on some condition given in R:

Say,I've a dataframe called x:

```
Data Needed
   3
```

The the output y dataframe should look like:

```
 Month_1    Month_2   Month_3
    10        13        25
```

And if entry in the input dataframe is:

```
Data Needed
   6
```

The output should look like:

```
   Month_1   Month_2    Month_3  Month_4    Month_5  Month_6
     10        13         25       18         11      29
```

I need some help in this as I'm new to R. Would be great if someone replies to this thread.

Comment: As for the column names, that's easy, `paste0("Month_", seq_len(DataNeeded))`. But where do those numbers come from?

Answer (score 0):

Please see as below:

```
create_df <- function(df, filler = c(10, 13, 25, 18, 11, 29)) {
  as.data.frame(matrix(filler[1:df$DataNeeded], nrow = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("Month_", 1:df$DataNeeded))))
}


df <- data.frame(DataNeeded = 3)
#      DataNeeded
# 1          3
create_df(df)
# Month_1 Month_2 Month_3
# 1      10      13      25

df <- data.frame(DataNeeded = 6)
create_df(df)
# Month_1 Month_2 Month_3 Month_4 Month_5 Month_6
# 1      10      13      25      18      11      29
```

However if you will call `create_df` function for `DataNeeded` > 6, you will need to provide `filler` argument manually